# MySQL - View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am currently working the first time with mysql and Views I came into it quite well but when I execute this SQL-statement I ran into an error. I sadly couldn't find a solution yet. It says that the view contains a subquery but I can't see or realise any subquery in this statement.

I am refering to this post: [Adding extra column to view, which is not present in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608464/adding-extra-column-to-view-which-is-not-present-in-table)

The guy there is using similar code and for him it is working, no idea why it isn't in my example. I also looked through Stackoverflow and saw a load of the same errors but the subquery was quite obvious in the other topics.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW 
`Worker_!view` AS 
SELECT * FROM 
(
   SELECT `Working_!skill`, 
   'asdf_!electrical' charserver 
   FROM `asdf_!electrical` 
   WHERE 1 ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1 
   UNION 
   SELECT `Working_!skill`, 'fred_!electrical' charserver 
   FROM `fred_!electrical` WHERE 1 ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1
);
```

#1349 - View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: View with Subquery in the FROM Clause Limitation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206062/mysql-view-with-subquery-in-the-from-clause-limitation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't work in MySQL.  Instead, you can do:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `Worker_!view` AS 
   (SELECT `Working_!skill`, 'asdf_!electrical' charserver 
    from `asdf_!electrical` 
    WHERE 1 ORDER BY `id` DESC
    LIMIT 1 
   )
   UNION ALL
   (SELECT `Working_!skill`, 'fred_!electrical' charserver 
    FROM `fred_!electrical`
    WHERE 1
    ORDER BY `id` DESC
    LIMIT 1
  );
```

Comment: oh damn right. That is for the oracle SQL language. Will test it shortly thank you!