# SQL: How can I define an extra column that is not present in a table?

Tags: sql, plsql

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608464/adding-extra-column-to-view-which-is-not-present-in-table#) helped me create a custom column, but how do I go about in defining what exactly should go in this column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an extra column by the selecting the column value or an expression. Optionally you can use 'as' and define your column name.
For example:

```
SELECT 
    T1.ID,
    T1.AMOUNT,
    T1.STATUS,
    T1.ADDEDBY,
    T1.ADDEDON,
    concat(T1.ID,T1.STATUS) as NEW_COLUMN1, //using an expression
    'output sample' as NEW_COLUMN2, //fill with a value
    1+3 AS NEW_COLUMN3 //using an expresion
FROM Table1 T1
```

I hope this can help you.
Regards

Comment: Thank you, I used this mechanism